# Convert or Use Laravel Routes from Blade file to be used in Vue Component

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

How to convert a laravel/blade route to be used in a Vue.js file.

I am in the process of converting a blade template into a vue component. In the `index.blade.php` I have a route that is used throughout the file that looks like:

```
   <a href="{{ route('product.show', ['id' => $product->id]) }}" target=""></a>
```

Now I want to be able to use the `{{ route('product.show', ['id' => $product->id]) }}` in my Vuejs file like so:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>My Products</h1>
         <a href="ROUTE_GOES_HERE" target=""></a>
    </div>
</template>
```

In my index.blade.php file I am calling the component like so with the routing bound:

```
<product :route={{ route('product.show' ['id' => $product->id]) }}"></product>
```

I am unsure how to use this in my Vue file though. What is the best way to do this without installing external packages or libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to pass the route as a property to the component.

```
<MyComponent :route="{{ route('product.show', ['id' => $product->id]) }}"></MyComponent>
```

So in your component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>My Products</h1>
         <a :href="route" target=""></a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            route: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
        },
    }
</script>
```

If you don't want to do it this way you can simply put the static route in your js file. Usually the routes do not change often

Comment: hello, I have added my component in my questions to show how I have the route set up in index.blade.php. But once I have the route as a property how do I use it in my vue.js file to replace the old route format? Thank you.

Comment: I see, when route is bound in my component then the href attribute in my vue file is using the bound value of route! Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to bind multiple routes to a single component call?

Comment: Simply pass an array on the property and change the type of property.

Answer (score 1):

MrEduar's answer works well for smaller cases. As the number of routes you're sharing grows, consider using something like [Ziggy](https://github.com/tightenco/ziggy), which generates a JS-friendly version of your routes, along with an API for interacting with them.